# Errors Message after migration to unified API

Tags: ios, xamarin

I just migrate my Xamarin iOS app to Xamarin Unified using the Migration Tool. The code below was working fine and the app didn’t have any error or warning before the migration. After the migration I got the following errors Error-1 PresentViewController doesn’t accept the MediaPickerController object as a parameter. Error-2 mediaPickerController doesn’t have the method DismissViewController

```
        protected void TakePicture()
{
    MediaPickerController mediaPickerController = mediaPicker.GetTakePhotoUI(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Name =  this.PictureName + ".jpg",
        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear
    });
    if (!mediaPicker.IsCameraAvailable)
    {
        ShowUnsupported();
    }

//Error-1
    PresentViewController(mediaPickerController, true, null);
    try
    {
        mediaPickerController.GetResultAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            BTProgressHUD.Show("Processing");
            // Dismiss the UI yourself

//Error-2
            mediaPickerController.DismissViewController(true, () =>
            {
                if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
                    return;
                }
                MediaFile file = t.Result;
                FinishedPickingMedia(file);
                BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
            });



       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Insights.Report(ex, ReportSeverity.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, I think you should clean your question. There are lots of unrelated lines, probably a copy-paste you did. About your problem, the unified API changed the methods a bit. Mac and iOS now use the same library. You will need to look for the right overloads and potentially another way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Xamarin component that contains MediaPickerController to the latest version compatible with Xamarin.iOS unified code!

The latest version of [Xamarin.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile) is 0.7.6. Double check with your project if your are using an older one.